# i am traying to insert data in table called drivers

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'drivers_name' in 'where clause'enter code here

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('drivers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('driver_name',999);
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('created by',999);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

class drivers extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
'driver_name',
'descrption',
'create_by'
];

```
use HasFactory;
```

}
select count(*) as aggregate from `drivers` where `drivers_name` = هشام عبدالله

Comment: Have you run the migration

Comment: The column is called 'driver_name' not 'drivers_name'

Answer (score 0):

you created column name is driver_name, not drivers_name